# Execute keyboard from file

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on a desktop application on windows 8, and the problem is that the touch keyboard does not automatically pop up in desktop mode, hence, I want to run the touch screen keyboard, based on its location,

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe
```

This is essentially the location of the on-screen keyboard. I would want to trigger it once the input is on focused, and where it would automatically close once it loses focus.

Below is the code I have

```
 addressInput = tk.Entry(self, font = "Verdana 20 ", justify="center")
 # Once the entry has gained focused, display the keyboard
 addressInput.bind("<FocusIn>", displayKeyboard)
```

I am not sure what command I should give to `displayKeyboard` so it can open this application.

Comment: `import os; def displayKeyboard(*_): os.system(r'start "" C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe')`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. the error that gets returned is The system cannot find the file C:\Program.

Comment: oops i forgot to quote the filename. that would be `r'start "" "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe"'`